# MySQL RegEx: Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column `participants` which contains a value like `"99005|99001|99002|99001999|99004"` which are user logins.

What exactly I want is to match `"99001"` without matching `"99001999"`.

Here is my method:

```
SELECT * FROM `bv_sklad_products` WHERE `stage`=4 AND `participants` REGEXP ('^([^\|]+(\|))*(99001|99005)((\|)[^\|]+)*$') AND `start_date` BETWEEN '2015-07-09' AND '2015-07-10' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

And the error message I get:

```
Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you can do it with `[[:<:]](99001|99005)[[:>:]]` if you need to find both `99001` and `99005`.

Comment: the real reason why it didn't work is because you need a double backslash before the pipe `\\|`

Answer (score 6):

You may use word boundaries.

```
regexp  '[[:<:]]99001[[:>:]]'
```

or

```
regexp '(^|[|])99001([|]|$)'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly! But how does the top one works?

Comment: [Here is an answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18902555/3832970).