# PHP MySQLi - order by case not rly working

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-order-by, case

This is my code:

```
   $q = '8gb pro';

   $sforeach = explode(' ', $q);

   $treffer = "when (titel LIKE '% $q %') then 1";

    $sortstring = "";       
    foreach($sforeach as $sf)
    {
        $sortstring .= "(titel LIKE '% $sf %') AND";
    }
    $sortstring = rtrim($sortstring, ' AND');

    $sortstring2 = "";
    foreach($sforeach as $sf)
    {
        $sortstring2 .= "(beschreibung LIKE '% $sf %') AND";
    }
    $sortstring2 = rtrim($sortstring2, ' AND');

    $sort = "order by case
                   $treffer
                    when $sortstring then 2
                    when $sortstring2 then 3
                    else 4
                    end, views DESC";
```

When I search for let's say  `8gb pro` then rows with `title` like `Acer TravelMate P648-MG-71S5` are displayed before rows with title like `Dell Radeon Pro WX 7100 8GB GDDR5` even though the condidion `when $sortstring then 2` should come before `when $sortstring2 then 3` and place it the other way around right?

Comment: Ah I see sry in my true code it's not really '$q' but $q it happend while putting a simple version here for better understanding. Please delete your comments ^^

Comment: We just don't have enough clarity -- we need to see some table data and your rendered query in action.  Are you able to mock us up an sqlfiddle demo link, so that we can see the issue being recreated?

Comment: Ok I'll try after checking some alternative order ways

Comment: It looks like the whole solution which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609166/mysql-order-by-like isn't working because I tried it with simple: $sort =  "order by case
    when titel LIKE '% 8gb %' then 1
                end"; and it still not working, display another order again though. So I really need to look for another solution

Comment: Ok I will when I don't find alternative, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your intended sorting logic is to perform multiple ORDER BY conditions.

Adding a space to the left and right side of your search string will mean that you will not accurately match when the first word or last word is the match.  For this reason, I must urge you to use the slower function `REGEXP` with its lengthy word boundary markers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8cHFC)) ([A basic SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a7892e/5))

```
$q = '8gb pro';
$parts = explode(' ', $q);

$sort = "ORDER BY";
$sort .= " (CASE WHEN `titel` REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$q}[[:>:]]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),";
$sort .= " (CASE WHEN `titel` REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . implode("[[:>:]]' AND `titel` LIKE '[[:<:]]", $parts) .  "[[:>:]]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),";
$sort .= " (CASE WHEN `beschreibung` REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . implode("[[:>:]]' AND `beschreibung` LIKE '[[:<:]]", $parts) .  "[[:>:]]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),";
$sort .= " `views` DESC";

echo $sort;
```

Output:

```
ORDER BY
 (CASE WHEN `titel` REGEXP '[[:<:]]8gb pro[[:>:]]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
 (CASE WHEN `titel` REGEXP '[[:<:]]8gb[[:>:]]' AND `titel` LIKE '[[:<:]]pro[[:>:]]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
 (CASE WHEN `beschreibung` REGEXP '[[:<:]]8gb[[:>:]]' AND `beschreibung` LIKE '[[:<:]]pro[[:>:]]' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
 `views` DESC
```

A [link explaining the word boundary syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18902555/2943403).

Comment: This is a very nice solution and works fine :D Thanks!