# How to make this REGEX below work for MySql?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have written regex and tested it online, works fine. When I test in terminal, MySQL console, it doesn't match and I get an empty set. I believe MySQL regexp syntax is somehow different but I cannot find the right way.

This is data I use:

```
edu.ba;
medu.ba;
edu.ba;
med.edu.ba;
edu.com;
edu.ba
```

I should get only `edu.ba` matches including; if there is some. Works fine except in actual query.

```
(\;+|^)\bedu.ba\b(\;+|$|\n)
```

Is there anything I could change to get the same results?

Comment: Maybe `(;|^)edu[.]ba(;|$|\n)` or just `(;|^)edu[.]ba(;|$)` will do. Why do you use a word boundary if the left and right hand contexts are stricter than a word boundary? You also should escape a dot if you mean a literal dot.

Comment: OMG! You are right, so simple, but I couldn't see it.. Thanks!
It is working :)

Comment: \b was unnecessary and it produced the wrong result.

Answer (score 3):

You want to match `edu.ba` in between semi-colons or start/end of string. The word boundaries are redundant here (although if you want to experiment, the MySQL regex before MySQL v8 used `[[:<:]]` / `[[:>:]]` [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901704/mysql-regexp-word-boundaries-and-double-quotes), and in MySQL v8+, you need to use double backslashes with `\b` - `'\\b'`).

Use

```
(;|^)edu[.]ba(;|$)
```

**Details**

- `(;|^)` - `;` or start of string
- `edu[.]ba` - `edu.ba` literal string (dot inside brackets always matches a literal dot)
- `(;|$)` - `;` or end of string.