# MySQL Select as if tokenized using Regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm looking for a string within the products model field that should be preceded or followed by a space, unless it's an exact match.

I can specifically use the four possible permutations by saying

SELECT products_id, products_model FROM products WHERE products_model LIKE '% UMA12' OR products_model LIKE 'UMA12 %' OR products_model LIKE '% UMA12 %'  OR products_model = 'UMA12';

but is there a regexp I can use to express this more succinctly?

This query should match

```
FOO UMA12 BAR
UMA12
UMA12 FOO 
FOO UMA12
```

but not

```
UMA1 
FUMA1
```

etc.

Comment: See [MySQL REGEXP word boundaries \[\[:<:\]\] \[\[:>:\]\] and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901704/mysql-regexp-word-boundaries-and-double-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find `UMA12` as a standalone word, then use `REGEXP` with word boundaries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE products_model REGEXP '[[:<:]]UMA12[[:>:]]';
```

Note: On MySQL 8+, you'll need to use slightly different syntax for `REGEXP` with word boundaries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE products_model REGEXP '\\bUMA12\\b';
```